# .htaccess sub directory in a variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to know if it's possible to point my domain to a directory which is two folders in from the root.

The point is, I inform the page that will be showed in the content area trought the URL variable, like this:

**www.dominio.com.br/index.php?c=products/list** (in this way, it works well)

I would like to access this path by using: **www.dominio.com.br/products/list**

This is my structure...

public_html

```
.htaccess    
index.php
**products**
    **list.php** <-- My desired folder.
customers
    list.php <-- My desired folder.
    new.php
```

I need a .htaccess code for read this URL with sub-directory folder in the variable. For now, I could make work when using the file in the same folder as index.php.

I hope this all makes sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
www.dominio.com.br/index.php?c=products/list
```

Works well for you, you could use a rewrite rule to map a 'virtual' folder path to your existing page:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/list$ index.php?c=products/list
```